# How to add custom fonts to kartik yii-mpdf in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

I know how to do it to make it work in local environment, I added fonts .ttf to `/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfonts`, and then added

```
$this->fontdata = array(
"calibri" => array(
'R' => 'calibri.ttf',
'B' => 'calibrib.ttf',
)
...
```

to `/vendor/mpdf/config-fonts.php`

So now I can use Calibri font in my pdfs, but what I should to to use it properly not only locally and after `composer update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I find:

1) put .ttf fonts in `/your/path/to/fonts/dir`, add `custom_config.php` with this content:

```
$this->fontdata["calibri"] = [
    'R' => 'calibri.ttf',
    'B' => 'calibrib.ttf',
];
```

2) in common/configs set path with custom fonts and to file with custom config

```
'mpdfCustomFontsPath' => /your/path/to/custom_config.php,
'mpdfCustomFonts' => /your/path/to/fonts/dir,
```

3) Somethere in your code before creating kartik/Pdf instance do this:

```
$customFontsConfig = Yii::$app->params['mpdfCustomFontsPath'];
$customFonts = Yii::$app->params['mpdfCustomFonts'];
define("_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS_CONFIG", $customFontsConfig);
define("_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS", $customFonts);
```

And this will work, because mpdf will check `_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS_CONFIG` and `_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS` while handling of html to pdf